# make Sitecore PowerShell script which takes input

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I have to make an interface to select items from 3 dropdowns and get the list of Sitecore items that are tagged to the items selected from the dropdown, I am a beginner to Sitecore Is it all possible by Sitecore PowerShell, can we make an interface to select input and use that input in the script by using  Sitecore PowerShell.
I am using Sitecore 10.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but this will allow someone to pick three items and write to the console if there are any items that refer to all three. Even if it's not exactly what you need, it does demonstrate how to pick three items from dropdowns in Powershell and apply some business logic to the selections.

```
$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
        @{Editor="droptree"; Name="selectedItemOne"; Title="Select first item"; }
        @{Editor="droptree"; Name="selectedItemTwo"; Title="Select second item"; }
        @{Editor="droptree"; Name="selectedItemThree"; Title="Select third item"; }
    )
    Title = "See what items are linked to three other items"
    Description = "Select three items to see what items are linked to all of them."
    Width = 300
    Height = 300
    ShowHints = $true
}

Read-Variable @props

$itemOneReferences = Get-ItemReferrer -Item $selectedItemOne
$itemTwoReferences = Get-ItemReferrer -Item $selectedItemTwo
$itemThreeReferences = Get-ItemReferrer -Item $selectedItemThree

if($itemOneReferences -eq $null) {
    $itemOneReferences = @()
}
elseif ($itemOneReferences.GetType().Name -ne 'Object[]') {
    $itemOneReferences = , $itemOneReferences
}

if($itemTwoReferences -eq $null) {
    $itemTwoReferences = @()
}
elseif ($itemTwoReferences.GetType().Name -ne 'Object[]') {
    $itemTwoReferences = , $itemTwoReferences
}

if($itemThreeReferences -eq $null) {
    $itemThreeReferences = @()
}
elseif ($itemThreeReferences.GetType().Name -ne 'Object[]') {
    $itemThreeReferences = , $itemThreeReferences
}

$intersection = $itemOneReferences | Where-Object {$itemTwoReferences.ID -contains $_.ID} | Where-Object {$itemThreeReferences.ID -contains $_.ID}

$intersection | Show-ListView -Property DisplayName, ProviderPath, TemplateName
```